# Proper formulation of Do expression

Tags: expression-construction

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
Do[
  P[x_, y_] := Sum[RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]*x^k*y^l, {k, 0, 3}, {l, 0, 3}],
  IrreduciblePolynomialQ[P[x, y]], 
  {12}]
```

Basically, I just want to generate multiple polynomials (in the above case 12) of the form

```
P[x_, y_] := Sum[RandomChoice[{-1, 1}]*x^k*y^l, {k, 0, 3}, {l, 0, 3}]
```

and have a list of whether these polynomials are irreducible. I don't actually need to see the equation of each individual polynomial, I just need a list of true, false so I can estimate some probabilities of irreducibility. Any help with this endeavor is immensely appreciated.

Comment: No need to put a definition, `IrreduciblePolynomialQ[Sum[(* stuff *)]]` works fine. You might want to use `Table[]` instead of `Do[]`, tho.

Comment: @J.M. Thats exactly what I needed, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Although I've told you that you can use a `Sum[]` expression within `IrreduciblePolynomialQ[]`, it will be more expedient for you to use dot products; that is, generate your random coefficients as an array, and then take the dot product of that with a vector containing your basis functions.

Thus,

```
Table[IrreduciblePolynomialQ[
      (x^Range[0, 3]).RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, {4, 4}].(y^Range[0, 3])], {12}]
```

should generate the list you want, after which you can use either of `Tally[]` or `Counts[]` to help you compute your desired probabilities.